# UIStoryBoard und UIPageViewController and initWithTransitionStyle

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

I'm confused on how to use story boards and custom initaliziers.

I need to call initWithTransitionStyle on the UIPageViewController.

But how to do that if the story board creates the UIPageViewController for me?

From debugging around, i can see that initWithCoder is called on my UIPageViewController.

Comment: Please stop writing tags in titles.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, there is only one transition style:

> **Transition Styles**
>
> Styles for the page-turn transition.
>
> ```
> enum {
>     UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl = 0
> };
> typedef NSInteger UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyle;
> ```
>
> Constants
>
> ```
> UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl
> ```
>
> Page curl transition style.
>   When the page curl transition style is specified, the page view controller displays a page-turning animation when transitioning between view controllers. If a data source is specified, the animation follows the user’s finger during a navigation gesture.
>   Available in iOS 5.0 and later.
>   Declared in UIPageViewController.h.

When they introduce others, I expect you will be able to define them in interface builder.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using storyboard (aka, dropping a UIPageViewController onto storyboard) it's already initialized, so I'm not sure why you need to initialize it.

If all you want is to change the transition style, navigation direction, page spacing, etc., these are all options in the Attributes Inspector tab.

Answer (score 0):

```
SecondViewController* bvc = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];

[UIView transitionWithView:self.view.window
                  duration:1.0f
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp
                animations:^{
                    [self.navigationController pushViewController:bvc animated:NO];
                }
                completion:NULL];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:bvc animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution of the problem:
here it goes: In the `appdelegate.m` file

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
     CountBookViewController *bc = [[CountBookViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:nil];
    [bc awakeFromNib];

    self.window.rootViewController = bc;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```